# Creating a dynamic blob container name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a blob container with a name based on a value (AssetID) passed into the function as a parameter.

```
    public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer(int id)
    {

        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnection"].ConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client 
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container 
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("AssetDocs" + id);

        try
        {

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist())
            {

                blobContainer.SetPermissions(
                   new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob }
                );
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return blobContainer;
        }

        return blobContainer;
    }
```

When I run the code I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: One of the request inputs is out of range.
```

I tried to add a try...catch however this does not seem to trap the exception so I can find more details.

If tried adding id.ToString() and also removing id altogether but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Cracked it! the container name must be in lower case.

```
 // Retrieve a reference to a container 
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("assetdocs" + id);
```